# color and background-color helper

Tags: css

I have 3 color combinations for the website elements

pattern 1 has

`background-color: rgb( 233, 239, 245 );` 
and

```
 color: rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
```

Similarly I have 2 other patterns but the font-styles, font-weight and size are different in different areas/sections.
How may I define 
pattern classes for such combinations, are there any best practices?

Comment: You can crate a class and give it in your html to all the element you want.
Like: class="black" an in your css write .black:#000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a meaningful class for each style and then apply it via the classes.

e.g:

```
.bold {font-weight:bold;}
.yellow {color:black;}
```

then use the html

```
<p class="bold yellow">This will appear bold and yellow.</p>
```

There are much more powerful options available in pre-processors like less and sass which allow you to mix and match classes using mix-ins